# Android TV - Prevent Screen Saver From Appearing

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I am creating a standard Android TV app which plays some videos and ran into an issue where screen saver turns on while I'm watching a video.

How can I prevent that from happening? Is there any trigger which I can trigger when I want for a screen to be ON all the time and prevent screen saver from appearing?

This looks like a good solution but screen saver still appears:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 2):

`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);` works on any device when it is set at the beginning of your activity. Where is that code being set? Is it in your main activity or also in your video playback activity?

You can take a look at the [Keeping the Device Awake](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html) guide for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `SurfaceView` to display your video, you should call `.setKeepScreenOn(true);` method of the `SurfaceView` instance.